# Data type conversion error in Access using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

When you enter date `31/06/2016` i.e. 31 June 2016

```
qdf.Parameters("Forms!frmReport!EndDate") = frm!EndDate
```

The error message is:

> Run-time error ‘3421’:
>           Data type conversion error.

Answer (score 1):

Uh huh ... and exactly what *else* do you expect?  **:-D**   It is, indeed, *impossible* to “convert” the 31st of June!

And so, the operative question:   *“Now what?”*

*“Aye ... here’s the rub ...”*

What you need to do is to set up a runtime-error handling block ("`on error goto` ... `resume next`" in Visual Basic) that will *catch* this exception whenever it might be thrown.

**BTW:**   the *reason* why things are done this way is that, “99.9% of the time, the conversion will *succeed*, until the user fat-fingers a key.”   Therefore, fat-fingers is:   ‘an *exception,’* which should be very-efficiently treated as such.   Instead of burdening our code with constant(!) checks to see if a date-conversion *succeeded* ... with potentally-dreadful(!!) consequences should we fail to include even one single miserable test ... we employ an exception-throw mechanism to single-out the (rare) cases when it doesn’t.

Therefore, “if you *do* ‘arrive at the next statement,’” you can be certain(!) that the conversion succeeded, because, “if it had not, you would not (immediately ...) *be* here.”

Instead of reporting their failures to you by means of a return-code, which obliges you “to test every one of them, every(!) time, more-or-less on pain of Death,” functions treat “exceptions to the rule” as the exceptions that they are ... and oblige you to be prepared to “catch” them.

Comment: Liked the way you explained. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open `frmReport` in Design View.
2. Select that `EndDate` control.
3. Open its property sheet, and choose *"Short Date"* for its *Format* property.

With that setting, Access will not allow you to enter an invalid date (such as Jun 31 2016) into `EndDate`.  And since it's already a Date/Time value, you won't need a datatype conversion when it's used for your query parameter.